# moderncv \cvitemwithcomment without bold font for the second argument

Tags: fonts, moderncv

Is it possible to use the `\cvitemwithcomment` without bold font for the second argument ?

MWE:

```
% compile with LuaLaTeX

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                     

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}

\cvitemwithcomment{German}{Native}{Mother Tongue}
\cvitemwithcomment{Frensh}{Native}{Mother Tongue}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Now it seems `\cvitemwithcomment` is deprecated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is.

Just insert `\mdseries` (which overwrites the default `\bfseries`) in the second argument:

```
\cvitemwithcomment{French}{\mdseries Native}{Mother Tongue}
```

Complete MWE

```
% compile with LuaLaTeX

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}

\cvitemwithcomment{German}{Native}{Mother Tongue}
\cvitemwithcomment{French}{\mdseries Native}{Mother Tongue}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

---

### EDIT

If you want to change this behavior globally in the document, you can instead add the following lines in your preamble

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\cvitemwithcomment}{\bfseries}{\mdseries}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvitemwithcomment}{\bfseries}{\mdseries}{}{}
```

so that your MWE becomes:

```
% compile with LuaLaTeX

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\cvitemwithcomment}{\bfseries}{\mdseries}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvitemwithcomment}{\bfseries}{\mdseries}{}{}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}

\cvitemwithcomment{German}{Native}{Mother Tongue}
\cvitemwithcomment{French}{Native}{Mother Tongue}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just a remark: are you sure you didn't want to write "French" and not "Frensh"?

Comment: you're right of corse. Thanks for these two fixes ;)